# Code coverage 0% with sonarqube 8.9 upgrade - scala project

Tags: scala, junit, sonarqube, jacoco

In console output, we are getting jacoco coverage report. but on sonar it shows 0% and project using build.sbt file. and in jenkins -Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=".../jacoco.xml" instead of - Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath="../jacoco.exec" still coverage shows 0% on sonarqube.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I have updated configurations of my project. I am able to see the code coverage in SonarQube 8.9 version

### Under project/plugins.sbt file

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" % "sbt-jacoco" % "3.0.3")
```

### updates in build.sbt

```
lazy val jacoco = Seq(jacocoReportSettings in Test := JacocoReportSettings().withTitle("Your service name").withFormats(JacocoReportFormats.XML))

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).settings(jacoco: _*)
```

scala version - 2.12.8

References:
https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/using-jacoco-a-code-coverage-tool-for-scala/